# Given the number of edges in a connected graph, how does one solve for the number of vertices?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, graph-theory

I know that given the number of vertices, the number of edges in a connected graph is $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. But how do we solve for the number of vertices, given the number of edges? I am stumped.

Comment: You eventually get a quadratic equation. One solution is positive, it is the value you want.

Comment: Do you mean a complete graph ?

Comment: Yes. A complete graph -- fully connected.

Comment: Ack! I'd missed the sign for $-2n$, so I'd gotten $x = \frac{1 + \sqrt{1 - 8n}}{2}$ which made no sense. Now I see it is $x = \frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + 8n}}{2}$. Thank you for helping me stay on track!

Answer (score 1):

Let $E = \frac{n(n + 1)}{2}.$ Multiply both sides by $2$ and rearrange, as follows: $$2E = n(n + 1)$$ $$2E = n^{2} + n$$ $$0 = n^{2} + n - 2E.$$

Using the quadratic formula with respect to $n,$ we find $$n = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1 + 8E}}{2}.$$

Notice that the root must be positive, so our answer is $$\boxed{n = \frac{\sqrt{1 + 8E} - 1}{2}}.$$

Comment: +1, although isn't the number of edges n(n-1)/2 ?? Unless we have loops.

Comment: You have the sign wrong. You are starting from $E = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ when it should be $E = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$

Comment: @supernoob, In any case, the problem is reduced to solving a quadratic equation on $n$. We need to solve $\frac{n^2-n}{2}=E$, there are many ways to solve quadratic equations, for example the general equation, in any case the answer is $n = \frac{1+\sqrt{1+8 E}}{2}$.

Comment: @dREaM Yes. Correct. See comment to original question. Thanks.